# Error al crear Formulario de Login en Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Tengo este Controller en mi proyecto de Symfony.
Intento crear un formulario de login básico

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login_route")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // obtener el error de login si hay
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // último nombre de usuario introducido por el usuario
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render(
            'security/login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
        // este controller no se ejecutará,
        // ya que la route se maneja por el sistema de seguridad
    }
}
```

El problema es que al ejecutar la página me salta este error. Entiendo que el problema está en security.authentication_utils pero no se exactamente como solucionarlo:

```
Service "security.authentication_utils" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\LoginController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.
```

Alguien podría ayudarme? No sé que puede ser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu error es que en Symfony 4 los servicios son privados por defecto, osea que no puedes pedirlo usando el método get del container.

La solución es sencilla, basta con inyectar la clase en el controlador y el autowire de Symfony lo inicializará por ti:

`public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response`

Luego solo tienes que usarlo.

Hay un artículo en la página oficial de Symfony donde explica en las detalle como construir un formulario de login.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html